# How to pass a csv to light more single leds in one msg payload with node-red-node-pi-neopixel library

Tags: python, node-red, led, neopixel

I'm currently trying to light up a 32x60 led matrix made of single WS2812B led strips. With the node-red-node-pi-neopixel node, i have to write 10 different msgs if I want to light up 10 leds that are not next to each other. Since the node uses a csv, it there another way to pass a more complex csv that uses ';' to light up more than one array?
Like '1,255,255,0;5;2550,255'.

Or if there are other ways, I'm more than happy to here from you!

Answer (score 0):

The node can't take an array, but you can achieve the same thing using a split node.

If you create and array of values representing the whole string of LEDS using `n,r,g,b` for each element in the array then pass this to the split node and then on to the neopixel node, it will break the array up into individual messages and send them in sequence.

You can use `n,0,0,0` for any LEDs you want to be off.